# How can I obfuscate HTML code so it cant be easily decoded by chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

When I obfuscate html code Chrome easily shows the original non-obfuscated html. I just need a simple obfuscation technique to make it harder to access the source code but the code cant be viewed in developer tools.

I tried obfuscating the html code to partially hide the source code but chrome developer tools got the original code immediately.

Comment: You could encode it with base64 in javascript. Note that obfuscation isn't a secure solution, in the end, frontend code (HTML) will always be visible and modifiable by the user.

Comment: In DevTools when using "inspect" you see the DOM elements, not the source code from which they were created. DOM elements can not be obfuscated, or else they wouldn't be DOM elements.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because DOM elements can not be obfuscated.

Comment: You would have to find a generator/encrypter tool that replaces all regular `<tagname>` with cryptic names, as well as all your selectors (Google, Meta, etc. do stuff like that). You can create your own `<tagname>` apart from 'official' *web-components* (a tag like `<VVWWVVWWVVV>` is perfectly legal), but you will obviously lose any HTML and User Agent defaults set in the browser. Additionally, all your text must be encrypted with a key and decrypted during runtime.

Comment: This might be something to your liking: [How to encrypt strings...](https://dev.to/bartosz/how-to-encrypt-strings-files-in-your-source-code-25e)

Answer (score 1):

The only secure way to protect your code is doing server rendering, in that way the client will only see what you wanna show

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.write(atob("PHA+dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q8L3A+"));
</script>
```

will output:

```
<p>this is a test</p>
```

Use your own string instead of "PHA+dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q8L3A+"

for example:

```
window.btoa("<p>this is a test</p>")
```

will return the string you want.

Again, please note: Obfuscation isn't a secure solution, in the end, frontend code (HTML) will always be visible and modifiable by the user